# How to make PHP drop down menu be taken as a HTML form input

Tags: php, html

So I've made a drop down menu (using PHP), and I'm not sure how to make it so that it can be taken as an input into a HTML form?

This is the PHP code:

```html
<?php
    $dropdownsql = "SELECT prodName FROM tblProduct";
 $dropdownresult = @mysqli_query($connect, $dropdownsql);

 echo "<select name='prodID'>";
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dropdownresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     echo "<option value='" . $row['prodID'] . "'>" . $row['prodName'] . "</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";

?>
```

And this is the HTML form code:

```html
<form action="addOrder.php" method="post">
  <p>
    Order Date*:
    <input type="text" name="orderDate" maxlength='70' required>
    <p>
      Order Location*:
      <input type="text" name="orderLocation" maxlength='255' required>
      <p>
        Order Product*:
        <p>
          Order System*:
          <input type="text" name="orderSystem" required>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Order">* Means that the field is required.
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE">
</form>
```

*Note that I want the input for Order Product

Comment: if you didn't set your htaccess to render `html` as `php` you can't use `php` codes inside `html`.

Comment: @roullie: Where do you see the file has the `.html` extension?

Comment: @roullie it's a php document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten this to make it secure. Check if it works for you:

```
        <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Link Games</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include 'header.php';
    include 'menu.php';
    try {
        $connect = new PDO("mysql:dbhost=localhost;dbname=linkgamesDB", 'username', 'password');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>
    <div id="content">
        <p class="headers"><strong>Add Order</strong></p>
        <?php
        #Check that the form is submitted
            if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
                #Create then run the query
                    $query= $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO tblOrder(orderDate, orderLocation, orderProd, orderSystem) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")
                    $query->bindValue(1, $_POST['orderDate']);
                    $query->bindValue(2, $_POST['orderLocation']);
                    $query->bindValue(3, $_POST['orderProd']);
                    $query->bindValue(4, $_POST['orderSystem']);
                    $query->execute();
                    #Check if there is an error in query and display relevant message
                    if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                        echo '<p class="records">Thank you! Record Added.</p>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<p class="records">Error. No record added.</p>';
                    }
            }
        ?>
<form action="addOrder.php" method="post"><p>
Order Date*: <input type="text" name="orderDate" maxlength='70' required><p>
Order Location*: <input type="text" name="orderLocation" maxlength='255'required><p>
Order Product*: <select name='orderProd'>
        <?php
            $dropdownsql = $connect->prepare("SELECT prodID, prodName FROM tblProduct");
            $dropdownsql->execute();
            $r = $dropdownsql->fetchAll();
            foreach($r AS $row):
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['prodID'];?>"><?php echo $row['prodName'];?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>
        <p>
Order System*: <input type="text" name="orderSystem" required><p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Order"> * Means that the field is required.
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay so that displays the information but how do I get it to take the selected item in the drop down menu to be taken as an input? Also the Order Product's name on the table is orderProd

Comment: Treat it like other input values in your PHP script that processes the form. i.e. grab the ID of selected product in your target page as $_POST['prodID']

Comment: This is my .php file for adding the input to the table. I have it already selected with $_POST['orderProd'] [link](http://codepaste.net/gwydwg)

Comment: Quotes are missing in $_POST values. i.e. $_POST[orderDate] should be $_POST['orderDate'] and so on. Moreover, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: When I put the quotes on the inside, $_POST['orderDate'] ,it gives me an error and I know that it isn't secure at all, it's a school project.

Comment: @BenHansen Check the updated answer. I have rewritten it to make it secure for you.

Comment: Thanks for that, however the values now aren't displaying in the drop down box (yes there definitely are values to pick from) also now there is no input box for the system and there is no submit button. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't notice the select part. There was an error. Now it should work fine. Check again now.

Comment: Thanks, it all displays but when I clicked submit it gave this error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object in (filename here :) ) on line 25   I've check and it's definitely called orderDate and it's spelt correctly everywhere.

Comment: Again missed something ;) corrected now. Check now please. Meanwhile I'll check it once more.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works properly now. Just one quick thing, is there a way to change that it enters the prodName instead of prodID into the table? Also you missed a semi-colon at the end of the  "$query= $connect->" line. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Don't worry, figured it out. Thanks for your help!